# Retrofit cannot be resolved with Gradle 3.1.2

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

After upgrading to Gradle version 3.1.2 from Gradle 2.x.x, `retrofit2.Callback` cannot be resolved. I use Retrofit in a submodule that is added like this:

`api project(path: ':sdk', configuration: 'default')`

The retrofit dependencyin sdk is added like this:

`api "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"`

My error message is:

`Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class ***, unresolved supertypes: retrofit2.Callback`

The IDE doesn't show me a problem within the class, that the Callback is missing somehow. The Android Studio version is 3.1.2.

What I tried so far:

- Cleaning the Gradle cache
- Clean build of project
- Updating Kotlin to 1.2.41

Comment: Use `implementation` for that https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2752

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya tried it with `implementation`. Still not working.

Comment: Sir, You can raise an issue https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui

Comment: Have you tried the Gradle Sync button on the left on the toolbar?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce which button do you mean exactly? I synced the gradle build after changing sth in the gradle file.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you resolve it?

Comment: @DigitalDa no not yet. #sad :D

Comment: For me the issue was that the class implementing the callback was a fragment and once I put the callback in its own class the error went away. I have no clue why..

Comment: @DigitalDa I added an answer for my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by disabling "Instant Run" on Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run.